# Partial Derivative Chain Rule Confusion

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

The question asks us to prove that,
if $ u = f(x, y) $, being $ x = e^scos(t) $ and $ y = e^ssin(t) $, show that
$$ (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2 + (\frac{\partial u}{\partial y})^2 = e^{-2s}((\frac{\partial u}{\partial s})^2+(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t})^2) $$

I know that about the chain rule with $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} $ and applying the derivative in terms of t, but what about $ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} $ when no function is given? How would you go about solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start from the right hand side,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial s} &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial s} \\
&= u_x e^s \cos t + u_y  e^s \sin t
\end{align}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial t} \\
&= -u_x e^s \sin t + u_y  e^s \cos t
\end{align}
Hence,
$$
e^{-2s} \left( (u_t)^2 + (u_s)^2 \right) = (u_x)^2 + (u_y)^2
$$

Comment: got it, thank you!